# Function returning undefined even though it is set before it returns

Tags: javascript, node.js

(NODEJS) Below I have a function that grabs data from a Redis server and returns the result. When I console.log the data in the getKey function it shows the data, however when it returns the data it seems be showing up undefined. I feel like it's something silly but it's been giving me a headache for the last few hours, any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
 function getKey(key) {
      client.get(key, function (error, result) {
          if (error) {
              console.log(error);
              throw error;
          } else {
            console.log(JSON.parse(result));
            return JSON.parse(result);
          }
      });
    }

function test() {
  console.log(getKey("abc"));
}
```

Comment: I'll help, you. Just try my solution, then we will examine next problem. But first we should solve "returns undefined" issue

Comment: Hi Nurbol, I tried the solution, I am getting returned true instead of the data

Comment: i am fixing my downvoted answer, it will be ready in moments